# I am using docx library and when i use docx.document('path/file.docx') it gives the error:module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document'

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am using the docx library ato read word documents
:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('C:/Users/gourabd838/Downloads/Initial Report with Scoring/INVESTIGATION REPORT.docx')
```

it gives the following error :"module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document'"
I have no clue why and am not getting any work around.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally caused by one of the following:

1. You have installed the legacy `docx` package rather than the `python-docx` package.
2. You have named your project `docx` and because it is in the local directory, it is receiving the `docx` name rather than the `python-docx` installation.

The predecessor (almost a decade ago now) to `python-docx` was called `docx`. They both install a `docx` root package, but the former is installed with `pip install docx` rather than the now proper `pip install python-docx`.

If you made this mistake, you need to uninstall the `docx` package and then install (or reinstall) `python-pptx`:

```
pip uninstall docx
pip install -U python-docx
```

If you have named the module you are developing `docx` you just need to name it something else (like rename the .py file if it is single-module or the directory if it is a package).